# Is this an old, alternate or incorrect way of writing 考?

Tags: kanji, calligraphy, old-japanese

Is this form of writing 考える correct? It has an extra stroke which turns the bottom portion into 与. I haven't seen it before and haven't been able to find it after searching. If it is correct, what kind of form is it?

[image: The 考える handwriting in question]

Comment: It could be wordplay (or characterplay) to add the sense of “give” to “think”, suggesting to think for other people or something or like. Where did you see it?

Comment: I asked someone to do calligraphy with 考えて for me and didn't ask them why it was written that way at the time (and just assumed it was some kind of old form). I didn't consider that you could play with the elements of a kanji to suggest other meanings. That makes sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. 考(father) has similar meaning and pronunciation with 老(old men in family) in its original usage in Chinese. It's written like [image] or [image] in 《說文解字》. The ㄎ part is a cane or walking STICK supporting an old man.
2. 與(give) or 与(the core part of 與) have completely different meaning although some part is written similarly. It was written like [image] or [image]. The 与 part is FOOD or soup or drinks inside a bowl, we hold it with both hands politely to give (あげる).
3. 攷 has its own meaning as knock or strike or hack. And was written like [image], expressing that a hand makes use of a STICK to strike. This is why it has the same pronunciation as 考. However, this writing becomes rarely used in China, most of the time we borrow 考 to express 'strike' or the similar. So as to 考える in Japanese.

**Conclusion**: [image] doesn't make any sense. People writing this way just mix up two things.

Answer (score 7):

Glyphwiki has [image: _] as an alternative glyph of [考](https://glyphwiki.org/wiki/u8003-ue0102), so it looks like more than one person write the character that way. I have never seen that, but perhaps it might not be so rare in calligraphy? (Bear in mind that the wiki page provides no source, though.)

Fun fact: 攷 is an alternative form of 考 and it's still used in Japanese words like 論攷.

Comment: Interesting. I was looking for a resource like glyphwiki